# Why use serverless functions instead of auto-scaling containers?

Tags: heroku, next.js, serverless, netlify, vercel

Platforms like Vercel and Netlify advertise their use of Serverless functions. However, what are the benefits of using these instead of auto-scaling containers that Heroku uses?
From what I've read, it seems like Serverless functions have cold start issues and limitations when it comes to DB connections.

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/concepts/conceptual-model for Vercel's take on that.

Comment: @juliomalves I have read through it, and the biggest takeaway was "In contrast, processes and containers tend to expose an entire server as their entry point. That server would then define code for handling many types of requests. The code you specify for handling those requests would share one common context and state."
However, if I deploy an Express nodejs app on Heroku, I don't think I've ever had to think about sharing context and state, Heroku does it all for you, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but that's not something Heroku would care about, that's something that would have to be handled you.